# Objective-C Present View Controller with its Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller like in the image below:

[image]

And I am trying to present this view controller from another view controller like so:

```
LHPDFFile *vc = [[LHPDFFile alloc] init];

vc.previewItemURL = self->_previewItemURL;

UINavigationController *navBar=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];

[self presentViewController:navBar animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This works, however my buttons are not appearing :(

It appears that the code above is creating a Navigation Controller instead of using mine with the buttons. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instantiating your view controller with the storyboard. Something like:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboardName" bundle:nil];
LHPDFFile *vc = (LHPDFFile *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"<id of your view controller in the storyboard>"];
```

Calling the empty `init` method leads to empty instantiation of the view, because you have never mentioned that it should use this storyboard's this view controller. More details [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/464-storyboards-tutorial-for-ios-part-1).

Answer (score 0):

You `init` none of your controllers from storyboard! Those buttons belongs to `file` view controller. You should `init` that controller from **storyboard** instead of call `init`.

```
MyViewController *vc = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"MyViewControllerStoryBoardID"];

UINavigationController *navBar = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];

[self presentViewController:navBar animated:YES completion:nil];
```